# Laravel Passport migrations not using default connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-passport

I am updating an application for my organization from Laravel 5.4 to 8.8.  One of the packages we're using is an OAuth2 implementation that is replaced with laravel/passport - so I'm trying to get that package working.

Following the directions here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#installation, I've installed laravel/passport, and want to apply the migrations.  Running `php artisan migrate` gives me an error saying "Database connection [mysql] not configured".

That's odd, because the default configured database connection is "uoda".

I have tried:

- In `config/database.php`, duplicating the connection details for `uoda` to `mysql`.
- Renaming `uoda` to `mysql` and changing the default connection to "mysql"
- Creating a new `config/passport.php` file that looks like:

```php
return [
    'storage' => [
        'database' => [
            'connection' => 'uoda'
        ]
    ]
];
```

but this file isn't even being called.

- Going into `vendor/laravel/passport/config/passport.php` and changing "storage.database.connection" to `env('DB_CONNECTION', 'uoda')`.  I changed this back to `mysql` after renaming the 'uoda' connection as mentioned above.

After each of these I call `php artisan cache:clear`.

Nothing I do seems to cause the migration to use the actually configured connection properties.  What am I missing?

Please ELI5 your responses - this is my first foray into Laravel so I know next to nothing about its intricacies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing an evidently important command:

```sh
php artisan config:clear
```